# Number of downloads of my iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone

Recently Apple has approved my app, i need to know the number of downloads of app. i have checked sales and trends in itunes connect but am confused what is units and ranking i want to find out total no.of downloads. Please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question may be closed but you can get your download stats through itunesconnect.apple.com

Comment: Thanks for ur response,i think my question is clear.i need to know the total downloads count of my app. Hope u get my point.

Comment: Go to itunesconnect, create an user with only read rights. Then go to appannie.com and enjoy a good dashboard ;)

Comment: @user3040319 The problem isn't with clarity. This question is off topic as it isn't about programming. Additionally, this information can be found (I think) more easily in the ITC mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps :

1. Log into iTunes Connect.
2. Go to Sales & Trends.
3. Click on the date in the top right hand corner.

This brings up a pop up menu that allows you to switch between daily/weekly/monthly/yearly.

Comment: thanks.. but i have already checked that, i wanna know the total number of downloads till now.

Comment: @user3040319: You can't get the direct total figure from iTunes. But it's certainly not impossible to sum up the download counts for all the prior years, months and days. Simple addition.

Comment: okay then can i count the apps downloaded per day as they displayed. is it correct count??